# where can I find vote down on my answer?

Tags: support, down-votes, profile-page

My SO profile is telling me I have two vote down against me.

where can I find the answer that have been voted down ?

thx

Comment: Emmm ... the votes were surely not _against you_ ... probably someone downvoted some of _your posts_ ...

Comment: @belisarius: you are right. I may have talked about vote against my answers.

Comment: @all: thanks for the help. However... the source of my question is because at a moment I had 440 of reputation,  and a moment later 439. I thought someone vote down one of my answer and I was looking for that. But a vote down is -2... not -1. Still wondering why

Comment: @Steve - a -1 is when you vote down another post. the -1 is to stop frivolous downvotes.

Comment: @cyberwiki: thx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the large up and down votes just before the tag section of your page (clicking on your username on the top bar), then those are the votes **you** cast, not against your questions or answers.

(As **BalusC** has pointed out, the above is most likely what you are referring to.)

*If you had wanted to find votes against your posts instead..*

A quick way is to go to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation and search for `(-2)`.  Each downvote will give you a -2 rep change.  Once you find the offending line, paste the number into a url:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234567   (if 1234567 is the number)

Comment: @Jon when the page gets longer, and going by the rule of not too many downvotes, searching for (-2) is way faster than paging multiple times (10x, 100x of pages?) and loading a lot of `HTML baggage` around the activities.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/588868/steve-b It are clearly the downvotes which he has cast *himself* against others.

Comment: @Bal - thanks, I didn't even think to check his profile directly

Comment: @cyberwiki: it actually helped me to find the vote down on my answers. Thx

Answer (score 3):

For recent downvotes:

Click on the envelope next to your user name at the top of the page.

[image]

You end up to a "Recent Activity" page. If you can't see the downvotes immediately, click on "yesterday", "this week", "last week", etc. until you do.